# Getting Image's Uri in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, uri, bitmapimage

I should get my Image's Uri but when I try to do it it is giving this error.

[image: Quick Watch]

Image's UriSource is able to casting BitmapImage but BitmapImage's properties are throwing errors. How can I get image's source?

```
img0.Source = GetImageForIndex(0, names, file, path).ImgSource;

ImageListTemplate GetImageForIndex(int index, List<string> names, IsolatedStorageFile file, string path)
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = file.OpenFile(path + names[index], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            BitmapImage tempImage = new BitmapImage();
            tempImage.SetSource(stream);
            imagePath = path + names[index];
            return new ImageListTemplate() { ImgSource = tempImage };
        }
    }
```

ImgSource's Type is BitmapImage already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not setting a URI source for your image, you're loading it from a stream of data instead.

The `BitmapImage` can be populated from a stream or a URI. You can only read the UriSource if this was set, by creating the image from a URI.

Based on your code, if you want a reference back to the original data source when querying the `SelectedItem`, I'd suggest storing that path/file information in the `Tag` property. Alternatively add it as another property of the bound items datasource and query that.